# Unmarshall XML with nested identical roots

Tags: jaxb, annotations, marshalling, unmarshalling

I really need your help. I've got this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<transaction xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" transactionName="KYGGT003" application="KYGG" version="01" country="ES" language="EN" type="S" enable="1" pre_event="0" pre_log="0"post_channel="0" post_event="0" post_event_functional="0" post_journal="0" post_log="0" post_rop="0" synchronizedJournal="0" priority="0" timeout="30000" jpa="true">
  <paramsIn>
    <parameter order="1" name="BANK-CODE" type="String" size="4"mandatory="1" />
    <parameter order="2" name="COUNTRY-CODE" type="String" size="2"mandatory="1" />
  </paramsIn>
  <paramsOut>
    <parameter order="9" name="ENTRY-BRANCH-CODE" type="String"size="4" mandatory="0" />
    <parameter order="10" name="ENTRY-EMPLOYEE-USER-CODE" type="String"size="8" mandatory="0" />
    <parameter order="11" name="ENTRY-EMPLOYEE-CODE" type="String"size="20" mandatory="0" />
    <group name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE" order="12">
      <parameter order="1" name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE- CODE" type="String" size="2" mandatory="0" />
      <group name="USERS" order="2">
        <parameter order="1" name="USER" type="String" size="80" mandatory="0" />
        <group name="PASS" order="3">
          <parameter order="1" name="PASS" type="String" size="80" mandatory="0"/>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  </paramsOut>
  <description>-</description>
</transaction>
```

And this is my java of GroupType:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "group")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "",  propOrder = {"parameter","group"})
public class GroupType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<ParamType> parameter;
    @XmlElement(name = "group", required=true)
    protected List<GroupType> group;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String order;

    public List<ParamType> getParameter() {
        if (parameter == null) {
            parameter = new ArrayList<ParamType>();
        }
        return this.parameter;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String value) {
        this.order = value;
    }

    public List<GroupType> getGroup() {
        if (group == null) {
            group = new ArrayList<GroupType>();
        }
        return this.group;
    }
}
```

How can I get the nested groups into the GroupType Object? I've been tried it for so long, testing several possibilities and I didn't find a solution.

Would you help me?

Thank you in advance, 
Regards. Pablo.

Comment: What you have looks good, what does the XML look like when you populate the object and marshal it to XML?

Comment: It only processes til first parameter: <parameter order="1" name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE- CODE" type="String" size="2" mandatory="0" />. The Object 'GroupType' only contains name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE" order="12" and the ParameterType Object but no the next GroupType nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should work.  Below is what I did to try it out.

### Java Model

**GroupType.java**

Same as you have in your question.

**package-info.java**

You need to ensure that your namespaces are mapped correctly.  If your package was `com.example` then you would need the following `package-info` class.

```java
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.w3schools.com",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

Below is the part of the XML document from your question that corresponds to the `GroupType` class that you are trying to unmarshal.  Note I added the `xmlns` declaration from root element of the document from your question down to the new root element `group`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<group name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE" order="12" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" >
    <parameter order="1" name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE- CODE" type="String" size="2" mandatory="0" />
    <group name="USERS" order="2">
        <parameter order="1" name="USER" type="String" size="80" mandatory="0" />
        <group name="PASS" order="3">
            <parameter order="1" name="PASS" type="String" size="80" mandatory="0"/>
        </group>
    </group>
</group>
```

**Demo**

Below is some code that unmarshals the XML to objects, and then marshals it back to XML.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(GroupType.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        GroupType group = (GroupType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(group, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Note the `parameter` element is empty because I didn't map any of the properties in my recreation of your model.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<group xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" name="AUTHENTICATION-TYPE" order="12">
    <parameter/>
    <group name="USERS" order="2">
        <parameter/>
        <group name="PASS" order="3">
            <parameter/>
        </group>
    </group>
</group>
```

Comment: Let me try and I give you the feedback! Thanks all for your time!

Comment: It doesn't work... What I'm doing is.... Jaxb2Marshaller deserializer = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
Class<?>[] clases = { Transaction.class, ParamType.class, ObjectFactory.class, GroupType.class };
deserializer.setClassesToBeBound(clases);
Transaction transaccion = null;
ParamsIn paramsIn = null;
ParamsOut paramsOut = null;
try {
 transaccion = (Transaction) deserializer.unmarshal(new StreamSource(flujo));
 paramsIn = transaccion.getParamsIn();
 paramsOut = transaccion.getParamsOut();
} catch (Exception e) {}

Comment: @user1068980 - Did you try my code using straight JAXB APIs?  Your comment indicates that you are interacting with JAXB via the Spring wrapper.  It appears the problem is related to the Spring layer.